# Is it possible in C to stop a pipe read with a signal?

Tags: c, pipe, signals, ipc

Hello i'm making a code that starts reading on a pipe waiting for other processes to write on, but at a certain moment a third type of process starts and signals the pipe waiter, at the moment that the pipe waiter receives the signal he must stop reading on the pipe and go doing other things, how can i achive that? I can manage the signal but i can't stop the reading.

```
void handlerp(int sig){
    printf("signal recieved : %d\n",sig);
    //Function that stops the reading
}

int main(){
    char buff[100];
    if(signal(SIGUSR1,handlerp)==SIG_ERR){
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    fread( buff, 100, 1,"PIPE");
    printf("I have stopped reading after the signal");
```

Comment: Instead of the `signal` function (which have ambiguous semantics), use the [`sigaction`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) function and make sure that the `SA_RESTART` flag is clear?

Comment: And you should probably be using the [`read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) system call rather than the C `fread` function.

Comment: Swapped to sigaction now it actually work, thanks , you saved my university project